# How can I pull a row through with grid_columnconfigure tkinter (Error)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a little problem with tkinter [Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNaqx.png):
The Black and white bar aren't pulled trough. Why not?

I declared the white bar in White Info Bar, and the Black Info Bar in Black Bar.
But they stop at the second Side Bar (Frame f4).

I want both upper bars to go trough the whole Window, but don't know how to do it.
Please give me some help.

A left a few unimportant things, like the fonts away.
Please forgive the mess.

My code:
And an Image (Display)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter as tk



root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")



# White Info Bar

f2 = tk.Frame(root, background = "white", width = 1, height = 30)
f2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew")


# Side Bars

f3 = tk.Frame(root, bg = "black", width = 1, height = 1)
f3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "nsw")
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight = 1)



f4 = tk.Frame(root, bg = "black", width = 1, height = 1)
f4.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = "nse")
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight = 1)



# Window

root.title("THE FRIDGER")
root.geometry("500x500")


# Black Bar


f1 = tk.Frame(root, background="black", width=1, height=45)

f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


# Black Bar Content


fridge = Label(f1, text = "Fridge", fg = "white", bg = "black")
fridge.grid(column = 0, row = 0, pady = 4, padx = 4)


recipes = Label(f1, text = "Recipes", fg = "white", bg = "black")
recipes.grid(column = 1, row = 0, pady = 4, padx = 4)


# Entry


content = Label(f3, text = "Content:", fg = "white", bg = "black")
content.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = W)


quest = Entry(f3, width = 36, bg = "white", fg = "black", relief = FLAT)
quest.grid(column = 0, row = 3, sticky = W)


content1 = Label(f4, text = "Content:", fg = "white", bg = "black")
content1.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = W)


quest1 = Entry(f4, width = 36, bg = "white", fg = "black", relief = FLAT)
quest1.grid(column = 0, row = 3, sticky = W)

root.bind("<Return>", analyse)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your info bars are in column 0 only, and therefore appear above the side bar that's also in column 0.  They are necessarily to the left of the side bar that's in column 1.  You probably want `columnspan=2` on the info bars, so that they can go over both side bars.

Comment: Boy. You earn a medal. Thank you so f****** much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of issues/misunderstandings.

1. assigning width and height to a `Frame` does nothing unless you also call `propagate(0)` on the `Frame`. You don't need to worry about doing that though cause, your app is based on `weight` and content.
2. using a `Frame` as a separator bar is noobish. Use a `ttk.Separator` instead. Make it thicker by adding `ipady` (if necessary ... or ipadx if vertical)
3. all of your stuff has terrible names that don't mean or reveal anything. To illustrate this, try to describe your code and take note of how much sense it does not make ~ "First I put the fridge and recipes in the f1, and separate it from the content with f2...". Now explain my refactor ~ "First I put 2 anonymous labels in a header `Frame` and follow it with a separator..". Names matter!
4. your `sticky` values are confused. You are attempting to consider the entire app with your `sticky`, but tkinter is just considering the cell each widget is in. For instance: `sticky='nse'` does not make the cell stick to the right side. It makes the widget IN THE CELL stick to the right side of the cell.
5. your header frame and separator are intended to span both of the columns below them, but you never told either to do that
6. you store references to every `Label` even though you will likely never change or remove any of those `Labels`
7. you double import `tkinter` AND use both syntax possibilities in your code. For instance: some of your stuff is `tk.Label` and some of it is just `Label`, but both of these return the same kind of `Label`. It's very sloppy.
8. rows and columns are not global. In other words, if you use `row=2` IN a `Frame`, you don't have to start with `row=3` FOR the next `Frame`. Similarly, if you put a `Frame` on row 3, you don't have to start it's children on row 4. Every `Frame` you create has it's own `grid` and it will always start with 0,0 indexes for it's children.
9. arguments for `tkinter` classes/methods can already become ridiculous in length. Doing this: `var = val, var2 = val2, var3 = val3` is not helping. Also, writing the exact same arguments across multiple widgets is not efficient. Prepare your common arguments for use as kwargs.
10. you start your app by configuring the root, but then you configure it a little more later on, and then a little more even later on. Doing this is a recipe for problems/errors/useless code. This is evidenced by the fact that you configured the same row twice, and assigned `geometry` twice. If you are working on a widget (including root), finish it (as much as possible) before going on to the next widget. Sometimes this is not entirely possible (like when attaching scrollbars to things), but it is generally mostly possible.

You can glean the rest from this refactor of your code.

```
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("THE FRIDGER")
root.geometry("500x500")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

#prepared data
dflt = dict(fg="white", bg="black")
pads = dict(pady=4, padx=4)

#header frame
header = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
header.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

for i in range(2):
    header.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
    
#header labels
tk.Label(header, text="Fridge", **dflt).grid(column=0, row=0, **pads)
tk.Label(header, text="Recipes", **dflt).grid(column=1, row=0, **pads)


#separator
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('custom.TSeparator', background='white')
ttk.Separator(root, style='custom.TSeparator').grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")


#left side content
l_content = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
l_content.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")

tk.Label(l_content, text="Content:", **dflt).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

l_query = tk.Entry(l_content, width=36, relief=tk.FLAT, **dflt)
l_query.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W)


#right side content
r_content = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
r_content.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")

tk.Label(r_content, text="Content:", **dflt).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

r_query = tk.Entry(r_content, width=36, relief=tk.FLAT, **dflt)
r_query.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W)

#root.bind("<Return>", analyse)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: a huge thank you first. I tried the code, but have questions: How can I make a frame right in the middle then? I tried it, but the code is always crossing with the last columns text.

Comment: @thething23 ~ copy/paste `r_content`, and rename it `m_content`. change `r_content` `column` to `2`. Change `columnspan` in `header` and `separator` to `3`

Comment: @Micheal Guidry  Thanks but now the whole frame is very little and sticks to frame on the rightest side. I want it to be one big in the middle of two sidebars. What can I do?

Comment: @thething - then you didn't folliw my instructions properly. However while you are at it give `m_content` a weight of 4 once you follow my instructions properly.